# return all pages which redirect to a page in wikipedia

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

Is there any way using the wikipedia api to return a list of all results which redirect to that particular page in Wikipedia?

(similar to the 'what links here' option on the left hand side of the page, but restricted to pages that redirect there).

Comment: Guessing you've seen rdcheck ? It seems to state that it's there specifically to find only redirects.  It's linked from the "what links here" page under "External tools" : i.e.: `http://dispenser.homenet.org/~dispenser/cgi-bin/rdcheck.py?page=Stack_overflow`

Comment: @hmedia1 - thanks - i had not seen that, and given it is na external service that wikipedia link to, i suspect they do not provide the ability to do this themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `backlinks` API module has a `filterredir` parameter. Using this parameter you can filter backlinks to redirect only. [Here's an example](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=backlinks&bltitle=Main%20Page&blfilterredir=redirects) of a query for all pages that redirect to `Main_Page`:

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 2):

The [Redirects API module](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Redirects) yields redirects with fragment identifiers (links to sections).  [[Example with Wikipedia:Disambiguation](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=WP:Disambiguation&prop=redirects&rdprop=title|fragment)]

In earlier versions of the API, only the Backlinks module was available.  It lists every page linked.  However, redirects are being categorized (WP:RCAT) with templates that add links.  This practice has make this module useless for finding redirects on certain pages such as: ASCII, Java package, Surname, Typographical error, etc.